# SQL - Distinct Not Providing Unique Results for Designated Column

Tags: sql, distinct

I'm currently learning SQL by working through these exercises: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

I'm on Example 8 which asks: "Show the name of all players who scored a goal against Germany."

Here is what I currently have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(goal.player), goal.gtime, game.team1, game.team2
FROM game JOIN goal ON (goal.matchid = game.id) 
WHERE (game.team1='GER' OR game.team2='GER') AND (goal.teamid<>'GER')
```

I would expect that results would be returned with only unique names. However, that is not the case as we can see "Mario Balotelli" is listed twice. Why doesn't the DISTINCT command work in this instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISTINCT operates on the record level, so you should use distinct for the whole row or if you need extra fields to show up in your result, you need to perform a GROUP BY on the player and bring along other fields by joining to the grouped result.

but i reckon the intended answer is only the player name, so query would be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT player
FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id 
WHERE (game.team1='GER' OR game.team2='GER') AND (goal.teamid<>'GER')
```

Comment: "you need to perform a GROUP BY on the player and bring along other fields by joining to the grouped result." What do you mean? Can you give an example of what "bring along other fields by joining to the grouped result" means?

Comment: actually if you only need the details of goals including player and goal time and teams, your original query without the DISTINCT directive will achieve the purpose. group by is for when you wanna aggregate stats based on certain player

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Mario Balotelli" can have multiple goal.gtime. Or can have different contributing values from Team1 and Team2. So try removing the additional columns you have in your select clause.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT gets the distinct rows based on all selected columns. As the goal times differ selecting that column will make the rows different (distinct) from one another.

The question only asks you to select the player's name

```
SELECT DISTINCT player
FROM game 
JOIN goal ON matchid = id 
WHERE (team1='GER' OR team2='GER')
AND (teamid <>'GER')
```

This link looks like it would useful further reading https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-an-sql-query

Edit: If you want more than one column but only a distinct list of players you are in the realms of aggregation, you would min/max/sum/avg the other data for the group.

```
SELECT player, team1, team2, MIN(gtime) AS min_gtime, MAX(gtime) AS max_gtime, COUNT(1) AS goals_scored
FROM game 
JOIN goal ON matchid = id 
WHERE (team1='GER' OR team2='GER')
AND (teamid <>'GER')
GROUP BY player, team1, team2
```

Comment: Thanks for the link on order of operations. Assume I wanted more than one column in my select statement. I've read that I can perform "Group by" as a work around: However, this doesn't seem to work either: SELECT goal.player, goal.gtime, game.team1, game.team2
  FROM game JOIN goal ON (goal.matchid = game.id) 
    WHERE (game.team1='GER' OR game.team2='GER') AND (goal.teamid<>'GER') 
GROUP BY goal.player, goal.gtime, game.team1, game.team2